# Мой код не работает, но не выводит ошибку discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Мой бот должен выдавать роли по реакции на емоджи, но он не работает. При этом в консоли не выводится ошибка. Вот мой код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  if payload.member.bot:
    pass
  else:
    with open('reactrole.json') as react_file:
      data = json.load(react_file)
      for x in data:
        if x['pubg_emoji'] == payload.emoji.name:
          
          role = discord.utils.get(client.get_guild(payload.guild_id).roles, id=x['pubg_id'])

          await payload.member.add_roles(role)

@client.command()
async def reactrole(ctx,emoji,role : discord.Role,*,message):
  emb = discord.Embed(description = message)
  msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed = emb)
  await msg.add_reaction (emoji)
  
client.run("My token")
Код файла:
["pubg_emoji":":pubg:","pubg_id": 817371069547020308]
```

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите на портал разработчиков, авторизируйтесь, выберите приложение бота, зайдите во вкладку `Bot` и поставьте галочки на пунктах в разделе "Privileged Gateway Intents".

Далее, в самом коде строчка с переменной `client` должна выглядеть так:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

Это было введено Discord'ом примерно в начале октября-ноября 2020.

Comment: Я это зделал, но код все-равно выдаëт эту же ошибку 